# What's the meaning of "progressive additions"

Tags: meaning

Could you break the sentence down below especially the part of "progressive addition"?
Progressive addition of 2 grams of the acid were made and resulted in reducing the pH succcessively by 0.34, 0.22, 0.16 and 0.10.

Comment: Have you looked up potential meanings of [*progressive*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/progressive#progressive__2) and [*additions*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/addition#addition__2)? What is confusing about them?

Answer (score 3):

In the context of the sentence, "progressive addition" means for every additional 2 grams of the acid that was added. The first addition of 2 grams of acid resulted in a reduction of the pH by 0.34, the subsequent addition of another 2 grams of acid reduced the pH further by 0.22. The relationship we see is that as more acid is added, the less effect it has on altering the pH of the solution.